# Add two variable numbers to one with html/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, streaming

I'm streaming to YouTube and Twitch.tv at the same time. To count my viewers i'm using a widget from the website streamlabs.

They provide me two numbers for each platform. One for Twitch.tv and one for YouTube. But I want to add these numbers together. I want a total viewers count. Sadly the widget from streamlabs does not support this. But it supports custom html text in a mini html editor at their website. 
I'm very bad at html and java script, but maybe someone here can help me? It can't be that hard.

This is the code from the widget to get the two count numbers.

```
<center><div id="platform_container">
</div>
<!-- platform item -->
  <script type="text/template" id="platform_item">
  <span style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}; margin:20px" id="{platform}_container">
    <i class="fa fa-{platform} platform-icon" style="color:{platform_color};"></i>
    <img class="platform-img" width="{font_size}" height="{font_size}">
    <span style="color:{font_color}" class="{platform}-count"></span>
  </span>
  </script>
```

I found out that twitch-count and youtube-count are the variables(?) the widget uses to show the counted viewers. So I wanted to add them to one number with a javascript. But it didn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var twitch = parseInt(twitch-count);
var youtube = parseInt(youtube-count);
var sum = twitch+youtube;
</script>

    <p id="sum"></p>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Can anyone help me please? :)

EDIT4: CRice did it! Big thx again for his awesome help. :)
Here is the html code I used:

```
<!-- all platforms will be added to this container -->
<center><div id="platform_container">
</div>
<!-- platform item -->
<script type="text/template" id="platform_item" >
  <span class="hidden" style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}; margin:20px" id="{platform}_container">
    <i class="fa fa-{platform} platform-icon" style="color:{platform_color};"></i>
    <img class="platform-img" width="{font_size}" height="{font_size}">
   <span style="color:{font_color}" class="{platform}-count"></span>
  </span>
  </script> 
<!-- table output which looks fine -->
<table style="border-spacing:0px;" margin="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" height="60">
    <tr>
      <th width=50><span style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}" id="{platform}_container"><i class="fa fa-twitch platform-icon" style="color:#6441A5;"></i></span></th>
      <th width=100><span style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}" id="{platform}_container"><label style="color:{font_color}" id="sum">0</label></span></th>
      <th width=50><span style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}" id="{platform}_container"><i class="fa fa-youtube platform-icon" style="color:#FE0000;"></i></span></th>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
```

And here is the CSS I used to hide the normal output from the widget:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And here is the JS I used:

```
document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {
    // obj will be empty for viewer count widget
    // this will fire only once when the widget loads
    makeSum()
});
document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
    // obj will contain information about the event
    makeSum()
});
function makeSum() {
    const youtubeCount = Number(document.querySelector(".youtube-count").innerText);
    const twitchCount = Number(document.querySelector(".twitch-count").innerText);
    const sumElement = document.getElementById("sum");
    sumElement.innerText = String(youtubeCount + twitchCount)
}
```

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough info to fully answer, but I do see a number of potential problems. First, to get the original counts, you'll need to pull the value out of the element manually. Since both elements look like they have a class `class="{platform}-count"`, you can use `document.querySelector` to find them. Eg:

```
// Note that you use a period (.) prefix to indicate that its a class.
const twitch = Number(document.querySelector(".twitch-count").innerText)
```

That will give you each count. Then you can add them together and set that number into the sum element. Again, you'll need to get the element manually so that you can manipulate its text. Since your sum element has an id instead of a class, you can use `document.getElementById`. Eg:

```
document.getElementById("sum").innerText = sum;
```

---

Putting all that together, here's an example snippet demonstrating this. Hopefully you can tweak it to suit your exact needs.

```js
function makeSum() {
  const youtubeCount = Number(document.querySelector(".youtube-count").innerText);
  const twitchCount = Number(document.querySelector(".twitch-count").innerText);

  const sumElement = document.getElementById("sum");
  sumElement.innerText = String(youtubeCount + twitchCount)
}

const buttonElement = document.getElementById("button");
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", makeSum);
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Youtube Count: </span>
  <span style="color:{font_color}" class="youtube-count">10</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>Twitch Count: </span>
  <span style="color:{font_color}" class="twitch-count">5</span>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="button">Click to calculate sum</button>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <p id="sum"></p>
</div>
```

Per discussion, try these snippets in their respective sections:

**HTML**

```
<!-- all platforms will be added to this container -->
<div id="platform_container">
</div>

<!-- platform item -->
<script type="text/template" id="platform_item">
  <span style="font: {font_weight} {font_size} {font}; margin:20px" id="{platform}_container">
    <i class="fa fa-{platform} platform-icon" style="color:{platform_color};"></i>
    <img class="platform-img" width="{font_size}" height="{font_size}">
    <span style="color:{font_color}" class="{platform}-count"></span>
  </span>
</script>
<div>
  <p id="sum"></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// Please use event listeners to run functions.
document.addEventListener('onLoad', function(obj) {
    // obj will be empty for viewer count widget
    // this will fire only once when the widget loads
    makeSum()
});

document.addEventListener('onEventReceived', function(obj) {
    // obj will contain information about the event
    makeSum()
});

function makeSum() {
    const youtubeCount = Number(document.querySelector(".youtube-count").innerText);
    const twitchCount = Number(document.querySelector(".twitch-count").innerText);

    const sumElement = document.getElementById("sum");
    sumElement.innerText = String(youtubeCount + twitchCount)
}
```

Comment: We are at the home stretch :D
I get the right number at the class="youtube-count" and for twitch as well. But i need the sum, that doesnt work so far. automaticly, no button to press.

Comment: I set the function to run when the button is pressed, but you can just call `makeSum` right away so that there's no need to press anything. But if you want the sum to update automatically whenever the twitch/youtube count changes, that's a lot more complicated, since you'd have to set up a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) on the twitch/youtube count elements.

Comment: Please read my edit2 of my question. The script doesnt work. The widget / custom html automaticly reloads. So we don't need a button, it will count automaticly.

Comment: Hmm. Per your edits, the sum element doesn't have an id (looks like you changed it to a class instead), so use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById` (just like for the other two). Second, in that snippet you are using `sumElement` before you declare it, which might create an error. Make sure the line `const sumElement = ...` is always before `sumElement.innerText = ...`.

Comment: Please read EDIT3 of my question. Maybe we can't figure it out and it's too hard.

Comment: Recall that for a query selector for a class, you need to prefix it with a dot. So change `querySelector("sum")` to `querySelector(".sum")`. Additionally, the `<p id="sum">` is empty because that one isn't being set anymore. Is your intention to set both the `<span class="sum">` AND the `<p id="sum>` elements? Seems like you only need one or the other. Finally, move the the `<script>` tag so that it's below the rest of the html. Wish I could be more help, but since I can't see whatever page you're working on, this is all just guesswork. LMK if this fixes it.

Comment: I know it very hard to help me. Thx a lot so far. If I move the </script> at the end, everything will disapper. :D Of course I need only one sum, not two. I changed the querySelector(".sum") too, but no other resaults, sorry.

Comment: If you are hardcore, go to https://streamlabs.com, login, connect your twitch and youtube account, go to widgets, viewer count, Enable Custom HTML/CSS and then you have the same environment as I do. There is a preview window as well, where you can see instant your resaults. But I'm just kidding, you don't have to do that!

Comment: Okay, I did the streamlabs thing and edited the post with what I got working. Just copy/paste those sections to their respective areas in streamlabs. LMK if that works. It doesn't look very good but the count is correct (at least it is when I tried it). You should consider learning a little bit of css so that you can add style to it and make it look pretty.

Comment: You are the man! It works perfekt. I did a few css/style things and post it here when I'm done. BIG BIG thx to you! :) Is there a chance to hide the first text/template script? I tried to hide it, but then the calculation was lost. If it's not possible to hide, I can move it out of my stream window. Not a big deal. ^^

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to hide? The template script is what shows the twitch and youtube counts. Is it that you only want the sum to be visible, and not the individual counts? EDIT: To hide an element, add css rule `display: "none"` to the style tag of the thing you want to hide.

Comment: Big thx again! Now it's working fine the way I wanted. I edited my question with the final resault. Have a nice weekend. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the total to the element you want to show it.

```
document.getElementById('sum').innerHTML = sum;
```

Comment: Okay I did that, but <p id="sum"></p> does not give any result. Maybe I can't use the twitch-count and the youtube-count, the way I want to use it?

Comment: under the var sum line add console.log('sum', sum); and check that something is output to the console

Comment: I got it, when I switch the twitch-count and youtube-count to numbers, it work. So I cant use the twitch-count and youtube-count as variables.

Comment: right, so the twitch-count and youtube-count variables aren't anything. @CRice has given some advice for that below